# React call parent load function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a series of filter buttons.

When I press one I want to pass the filter being applied back up to the parent and for the parent to reload the data (coming from the server via ajax).

My filter buttons:

```
var FilterButton = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            active: false
        };
    },
    handleClick: function (e) {
        this.setState({active: !this.state.active});
        console.log(this.props.filters);
        JobList.load(); // Doesn't work ofcourse
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick} className={'btn btn-filter btn-sm'+(this.state.active ? ' active' : '')}><span
                className="filter-name">{this.props.name}</span><span className="filter-count">{this.props.count}</span>
            </button>
        )
    }
});
```

The parent:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            filters: []
        };
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 job-list"><JobList /></div>
                <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 panel-container">
                    <div className="right-panel pull-right"><RightPanel /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
})
```

What do I need to do to get the filter component to pass its filter up to the parent and for it to apply and load JobList?:

```
var JobList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            jobs: []
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.load();
    },
    load: function () {
        var self = this;
        qwest.get('jobs/list', null, {responseType: 'json'})
            .then(function (response) {
                var jobs = response.map(function (job) {
                    return (<Job key={job.id} job={job}/>);
                });
                self.setState({jobs: jobs});
            })
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.jobs}
            </div>
        );
    }
})
```

---

FilterButton is used here:

```
var RightPanel = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            counts: {}
        }
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.load();
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if (newProps.counts) {
            this.setState({
                counts: newProps.counts
            });
        }
    },
    load: function () {
        this.setState({
            counts: {
                my_jobs: 1,
                not_approved: 5
            }
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <span className="title">Filters</span>

                    <FilterButton name='My jobs' count={this.state.counts.my_jobs}/>
                    <FilterButton name='Not approved' count={this.state.counts.not_approved}/>
                    <FilterButton name='Supply' count={this.state.counts.supply}/>
                    <FilterButton name='Repair' count={this.state.counts.repair}/>
                    <FilterButton name='Service exchange' count={this.state.counts.service_ex}/>
                    <FilterButton name='Urgent' count={this.state.counts.urgent}/>
                    <FilterButton name='Today' count={this.state.counts.today}/>
                    <FilterButton name='Overdue' count={this.state.counts.overdue}/>
                </div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <span className="title">Sorts</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

---

Example of data coming in, just one record for the example:

```
[{"id":40762,"dateCreated":"12\/04\/2016 at 06:04","display_code":"EU","display_number":40667,"entity_name":"INA Kysuce, spol. s r.o.","enquiry_id":134886,"approval_date":"12\/04\/2016 at 06:04","countryCode":"CZ","country":"Czech Republic","sales_area_name":"CZ (Unknown)","nth_job":"6th","service_types":"1","approved_by":"Alex","user_name":"Marek","cex_user_name":"Alex","oft_user_name":"Simon","urgency":2,"age":"6 hours ago","name":"EU-J40667","has_repair":0,"has_supply":1,"has_servicex":0}]
```

---

Full JS:

```
'use strict';

var container = document.getElementById('container');

var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            filters: []
        };
    },
    toggleFilter: function (name) {
        // Add or remove the filter to the current state.
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 job-list"><JobList filters={this.state.filters}/></div>
                <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 panel-container">
                    <div className="right-panel pull-right"><RightPanel toggleFilter={this.toggleFilter}/></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
})

var JobList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            jobs: []
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.load();
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps: function (nextProps) {
        this.load();
    },
    load: function () {
        var self = this;
        qwest.get('jobs/list', null, {responseType: 'json'})
            .then(function (response) {
                var jobs = response.map(function (job) {
                        return (<Job key={job.id} job={job}/>);
                    });
                self.setState({jobs: jobs});
            })
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.jobs}
            </div>
        );
    }
})

var Job = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            return (
                <div className="job">
                    <div className="job-header">
                        <a target="_blank"
                           href={'/activity/'+this.props.job.enquiry_id}>{this.props.job.name}</a>
                        <img
                            width="16"
                            src={'/images/flags/'+(this.props.job.countryCode ? this.props.job.countryCode : 'large/WW')+'.png'}
                            title={this.props.job.country ? this.props.job.country+' - '+this.props.job.sales_area_name : 'Country not set for sales area '+this.props.job.sales_area_name}
                            /> - {this.props.job.entity_name} - <span className="ordinal">({this.props.job.nth_job}
                        job)</span>
                        <abbr className="pull-right" title={this.props.job.dateCreated}>{this.props.job.age}</abbr>

                    </div>
                    <div className="job-body">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-xs-12">
                                <div className="row users">
                                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                                        <span className="title">Trader</span>
                                        <span className="name">{this.props.job.user_name}<img
                                            src="/images/system-icons/pencil.png" width="13"
                                            title="Change which trader owns this job."/></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                                        <span className="title">CEX</span>
                                        <span
                                            className="name">{this.props.job.cex_user_name ? this.props.job.cex_user_name : 'None assigned'}</span>

                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                                        <span className="title">OFT</span>
                                        <span
                                            className="name">{this.props.job.oft_user_name ? this.props.job.oft_user_name : 'None assigned'}<img
                                            title="Set the OFT user for this job." src="/images/system-icons/pencil.png"
                                            width="13"/></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="job-footer">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
                                <div className="btn-group urgency" role="group" aria-label="...">
                                    <UrgencyToggle urgency={this.props.job.urgency} job_id={this.props.job.id}/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
                                <div className="dropdown pull-right">
                                    <button className="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button"
                                            id="form_menu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                            aria-expanded="true">
                                        <i className="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i> Forms
                                    </button>
                                    <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="form_menu">
                                        <li><a target="_blank" href={'/quote/'+this.props.job.enquiry_id}>Quote</a></li>
                                        <li><a target="_blank"
                                               href={'/proforma/'+this.props.job.enquiry_id}>Proforma</a></li>
                                        <li><a target="_blank" href={'/order-confirmation/'+this.props.job.enquiry_id}>Order
                                            confirmation</a></li>
                                        <li><a target="_blank" href={'/delivery-note/'+this.props.job.enquiry_id}>Delivery
                                            note</a></li>
                                        <li><a target="_blank" href={'/commercial-invoice/'+this.props.job.enquiry_id}>Commercial
                                            invoice</a></li>
                                        <li><a target="_blank" href={'/invoice/'+this.props.job.enquiry_id}>Invoice</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <span
                                    className={'approved pull-right'+(this.props.job.approval_date ? ' green' : ' red')}
                                    title={(this.props.job.approval_date ? 'Approved on '+this.props.job.approval_date+' by '+this.props.job.approved_by : 'Job not approved yet')}
                                    ></span>

                                <div className="part-types-within pull-right">
                                    <div className="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                                        <button type="button"
                                                className={'btn '+(this.props.job.has_supply ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-default')}
                                                title={this.props.job.has_supply ? 'This job has parts for supply' : 'This job has no parts for supply'}>
                                            Su
                                        </button>
                                        <button type="button"
                                                className={'btn '+(this.props.job.has_repair ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-default')}
                                                title={this.props.job.has_repair ? 'This job has parts to be repaired' : 'This job has no parts to be repaired'}>
                                            Re
                                        </button>
                                        <button type="button"
                                                className={'btn '+(this.props.job.has_servicex ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-default')}
                                                title={this.props.job.has_servicex ? 'This job has parts to be exchanged' : 'This job has no parts to be exchanged'}>
                                            Sx
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
);

var UrgencyToggle = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function () {
        this.setState({
            job_id: this.props.job_id
        });
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            urgency: this.props.urgency
        };
    },
    handleClick: function (number) {
        this.setState({urgency: number});
        qwest.post('jobs/set/urgency', {id: this.props.job_id, urgency: number})
            .then(function (response) {

            })
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 1)} type="button"
                            className={'btn '+(this.state.urgency == 1 ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-default btn-faded' )}>
                        Urgent
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 2)} type="button"
                            className={'btn '+(this.state.urgency == 2 ? 'btn-warning' : 'btn-default btn-faded' )}>
                        To action
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 3)} type="button"
                            className={'btn '+(this.state.urgency == 3 ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-default btn-faded' )}>
                        Progressing
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var RightPanel = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            counts: {}
        }
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.load();
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        if (newProps.counts) {
            this.setState({
                counts: newProps.counts
            });
        }
    },
    load: function () {
        this.setState({
            counts: {
                my_jobs: 1,
                not_approved: 5
            }
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <span className="title">Filters</span>

                    <FilterButton name='My jobs' count={this.state.counts.my_jobs} toggleFilter={this.props.toggleFilter}/>
                    <FilterButton name='Not approved' count={this.state.counts.not_approved} toggleFilter={this.props.toggleFilter}/>
                    <FilterButton name='Supply' count={this.state.counts.supply} toggleFilter={this.props.toggleFilter}/>
                    <FilterButton name='Repair' count={this.state.counts.repair} toggleFilter={this.props.toggleFilter}/>
                    <FilterButton name='Service exchange' count={this.state.counts.service_ex} toggleFilter={this.props.toggleFilter}/>
                    <FilterButton name='Urgent' count={this.state.counts.urgent} toggleFilter={this.props.toggleFilter}/>
                    <FilterButton name='Today' count={this.state.counts.today} toggleFilter={this.props.toggleFilter}/>
                    <FilterButton name='Overdue' count={this.state.counts.overdue} toggleFilter={this.props.toggleFilter}/>
                </div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <span className="title">Sorts</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var FilterButton = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            active: false
        };
    },
    handleClick: function (e) {
        this.setState({active: !this.state.active});
        this.props.toggleFilter(this.props.name);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick} className={'btn btn-filter btn-sm'+(this.state.active ? ' active' : '')}><span
                className="filter-name">{this.props.name}</span><span className="filter-count">{this.props.count}</span>
            </button>
        )
    }
});

var ClearFiltersButton = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <button className={'btn btn-filter btn-sm'+(this.props.active ? ' active' : '')}><span
                className="filter-name">Clear filters</span><span
                className="filter-count">{this.state.counts.count()}</span></button>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, container);
```

Comment: You must move load function to App and give to JobList more data, and in FilterButton you also just in props put callback that on click will be called, this callback is function that start load in app. Need example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
var FilterButton = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            active: false
        };
    },
    handleClick: function (e) {
        this.setState({active: !this.state.active});
        this.props.toggleFilter(this.props.name);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick} className={'btn btn-filter btn-sm'+(this.state.active ? ' active' : '')}><span
                className="filter-name">{this.props.name}</span><span className="filter-count">{this.props.count}</span>
            </button>
        )
    }
});
```

---

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            filters: []
        };
    },
    toggleFilter: function (name) {
       // Add or remove the filter to the current state. this is just an example.
       var filter_array = [];
       filter_array.push(name);
       this.setState({filters: filter_array});
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 job-list">
                    <JobList filters={this.state.filters} />
                </div>
                <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 panel-container">
                    <div className="right-panel pull-right">
                        <RightPanel toggleFilter={this.toggleFilter} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
})
```

---

```
var JobList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            jobs: []
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.load();
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps: function (nextProps) {
        this.load();
    },
    load: function () {
        var self = this;
        qwest.get('jobs/list', {filters: this.props.filters}, {responseType: 'json'})
            .then(function (response) {
                var jobs = response.map(function (job) {
                        return (<Job key={job.id} job={job}/>);
                    });
                self.setState({jobs: jobs});
            });
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.jobs}
            </div>
        );
    }
})
```

---

```
var RightPanel = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <span className="title">Filters</span>

                    <FilterButton name='My jobs' count={this.state.counts.my_jobs} toggleFilter={this.props.toggleFilter}/>
                    // The other filters here
                </div>
                <div className="controls">
                    <span className="title">Sorts</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

The extra code manages the filters at the top level. Each filter knows if it has been clicked, but technically it should probably get the list of active filters as a prop and work out if it is active.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the state in the *RightPanel*, but it doesn't look right to me. You should just use the props directly rather than copying to state each time.

Comment: return this.props.filters.some((filter) => ) // apply this filters here is giving me the error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text

Comment: @imperium2335 What are your filters supposed to do?

Comment: @imperium2335 i.e. how do you determine what constitutes a job is 'your job' or 'not approved'?

Comment: The server would apply the filters but the jobs have data in them, I'll do an edit...

Comment: @imperium2335 you could remove the filter from the results completely then and pass in the filters as query parameters to the server

Comment: @imperium2335 I've just had another thought, which is that you will also need to trigger the load in _JobList_ when the filters change, so you might need to look up willReceiveNewProps or didReceiveNewProps to trigger the ajax call again.

Comment: Yes, I have no idea how to do that as I am green to React :(

Comment: @imperium2335 I've updated my answer to cover the updating issue and remove the filter for the results and pass in the filters to the server.

Comment: How do I get this to fire the ajax call though? It's not at the moment :/

Comment: componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps should fire the ajax, are you getting any output in your console, do you have a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: I have edited in the full js code with your changes. I can't create a fiddle sadly as my app has many dependencies etc

Comment: It works now, I did:toggleFilter: function (name) {
        // Add or remove the filter to the current state.
        var filter_array = [];
        filter_array.push(name)
        this.setState(filter_array);
    },

Comment: Ok, great. I'll edit my answer to include that then.